# Extract elements of a list of tuples based on elements in another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of lists

```
list_x =  [['0', '2', '3'], ['8']]
```

and a list of tuples

```
list_tuples = [
(['0', '2', '3'], ['Start', '1', '2', '2', '9', '9', '9', '10', '15', 'End'], 1),
 (['8'], ['Start', '15', '16', '11', '2', '7', '1', 'End'], 2),
 (['1'], ['Start', '7', '1', '9', '4', '16', 'End'], 3),
 (['6'], ['Start', '15', '10', '7', 'End'], 4)]
```

I want to extract those tuples from `list_tuples` whose first element is listed in `list_x`.
The desired output is

```
list_output = [
(['0', '2', '3'], ['Start', '1', '2', '2', '9', '9', '9', '10', '15', 'End'], 1),
 (['8'], ['Start', '15', '16', '11', '2', '7', '1', 'End'], 2)]
```

I tried it by using `itemgetter` (`from operator import itemgetter`). It works well with dicts but I could not apply it to this problem since it cannot work with a list as a list index (at least that is what the error said).

```
list_output = list(list_x, (itemgetter(*list_x)(list_tuples)))
```

Any solution would be great (a solution with `itemgetter` would be even greater).  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
list_output = [v for v in list_tuples if v[0] in list_x]
print(list_output)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    (
        ["0", "2", "3"],
        ["Start", "1", "2", "2", "9", "9", "9", "10", "15", "End"],
        1,
    ),
    (["8"], ["Start", "15", "16", "11", "2", "7", "1", "End"], 2),
]
```

Comment: I was going to post the same thing! :(. Any way, that is the shortest and the most logical answer. So +1

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Wow, that was fast. Thank you. When I looked for a solution myself I saw such solutions too. What irritates me is the logic behind 'v for v' is. I know that it somehow iterates over list_tuples but why is v mentioned twice in this expression?

Answer (score 1):

used filter since no `v in v` logic

```py
list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in list_x, list_tuples))
```

Using itemgetter, not the fastest i guess since the entries are list and not hashable like tuple (felt like touching your left ear with right hand from behind the head)

```py
list_x =  [['0', '2', '3'], ['8']]
list_tuples = [
(['0', '2', '3'], ['Start', '1', '2', '2', '9', '9', '9', '10', '15', 'End'], 1),
 (['8'], ['Start', '15', '16', '11', '2', '7', '1', 'End'], 2),
 (['1'], ['Start', '7', '1', '9', '4', '16', 'End'], 3),
 (['6'], ['Start', '15', '10', '7', 'End'], 4)]
list_x = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x), list_x))
list_tuples = list(map(lambda x: (tuple(x[0]), x), list_tuples))

itemgetter(*list_x)(dict(list_tuples))
```